# How do you automatically scroll a div (Horizontally) which contains plain text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, text, scroll

Please bear with me here! I familiarized myself with basic HTML and decided web programming would be my occupation. I enrolled in a program and am now writing my first live project in my fourth semester. Our classes deal mainly in the .NET Framework and I am very unfamiliar with Javascript and client-side programming in general.

Hopefully I outline this information enough to give the great members of this community a chance to help a budding developer.

Objective: Scroll a div containing plain text horizontally across a page indefinitely
Environment: Windows server running ASP.NET 4.0.
Language: C#/XHTML/Javascript
Tools Used: jQuery, jQueryTools, SmoothDivScroll

I have attempted to use a jQuery plugin known as SmoothDivScroll as well as jQueryTools to execute my objective, however, with my lack of client-side experience, I have had absolutely no success.

My webpage is available at http://paysonfirstassembly.com/ and the div that I am attempting to scroll has a class and ID of scrollingPanel.

I can provide sample code if it will help.

-Taylor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to fit your needs: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqScroller

```
<style type="text/css">

  /* CSS for the scrollers */
  #scrollingPanel{
    position:relative;
    height:24px;
    width:500px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:#CCCCCC 1px solid;
  }

  .scrollingtext{
      position:absolute;
      white-space:nowrap;
  }
</style>

$(document).ready(function() {

    //create a horizontal scroller
    $('#scrollingPanel').SetScroller({
        velocity: 80,
        direction: 'horizontal'
        //more tweaks on the source code of plugin page
    });


});
```

your HTML should be like this:

```
<div id="scrollingPanel">
    <div class="scrollingtext">
        Making a Difference in People
    </div>
</div>
```

See [this page](http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_scroller/) source code for more functions and tweaks

Comment: I've changed my markup to resemble that, except that I used a class of scrollingPanel for the container, instead of the ID. I also changed the script to use a class selector instead of an ID. The text now appears on the left side of the container instead of the right, however, it does NOT scroll.

I've just updated the live code and I hope that you can continue to help me out. I believe this is the simplest approach and appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Plugin source code is not loaded, check for the right path of jquery.Scroller-1.0.min.js

Comment: Also include the script in $(document).ready(), i edited my answer

Comment: Alright, I'm not entirely sure how to do that though. Like I said, my client-side programming is very minimal. If you could provide a code example I believe the problem would be solved. I understand what the document.ready method does, but am unsure of how to implement it.

Comment: Ok, but the main problem is that Plugin source code is not loaded. You must to change src="jquery.Scroller-1.0.min.js", to match with the correct path in your server.

Comment: I have done so, though I haven't uploaded the files again to the website. In my production environment the path has been changed to src="Scripts/jquery.Scroller-1.0.min.js", yet I still encounter the same problem (Text floating on left without scrolling)

Comment: Argh, this is so frustrating. I understand the edits to the answer you have made and implemented them, however the script is still not running properly. I've decided to downgrade my jQuery to see if this fixes the issue (They use 1.4.1 minified on the example site)

Comment: Hey! read comments! use $(document).ready(function() { ... });

Comment: I did that! It doesn't work!! The code looks like this.

`code`$(document).ready(function() {

    //create a horizontal scroller
    $('#scrollingPanel').SetScroller({
        velocity: 80,
        direction: 'horizontal'
    });

});
`code`

Comment: Yeah, there was a missing rule on style. I've updated the script above.

Comment: Just to clarify, although the style you've added is necessary, the particular issue with my code was putting javascript within a script tag that had a src attribute.

Thanks so much for your time(:

Answer (score 2):

Remy Sharp has a good jQuery Marquee implementation [here](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/) with [some demos](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html). This allows you to do

```
<div class='marquee'>Scroll this</div>
```

and then

```
$('.marquee').marquee();
```

with his plug-in included.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your text in marquee tag like this

```
<div class="scrollingPanel">
    <marquee>Making a Difference in People</marquee>
</div>
```

Though, I personally DO NOT RECOMMEND this solution. But it will work for your college project like charm. It doesn't need any external scripts.

Comment: Don't seriously use `marquee` tags, what is this 1995?

Comment: Come on guys, Its just a college project!